# Returning a reference to the derived class from a base class method

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a task to implement a simple SVG generator. I need to support Circle, Polyline and Text. All three have at least 4 common methods:
- SetStrokeColor
- SetFillColor
- SetStrokeWidth
- ToString
One of the main requirements is to **support chaining**, e.g.:
Polyline{}.SetStrokeColor("white").SetFillColor("black")...

I decided to implement a base class Element, which all the other classes inherit from. The idea is to have a class Document that holds a vector of all the elements added to the document.
A sample signature for a base method:

```cpp
// source of trouble
Element &SetStrokeColor(const Color &color) {
    ...
    return *this;
}
```

My derived classes do call these methods, but the trouble is that the methods return a reference to the base class Element, not the derived class.

My question is whether it is all together possible to implement in c++???

[Further discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221660/method-chain-a-derived-class-method-after-calling-a-base-class-method?rq=1)

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), retake [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and reread about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please don't forget how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Not a problem at all - solely that *your* signature has a surplus ampersand...

Comment: @Aconcagua typo

Comment: a reference to the base is a an abstract reference to the derived class. what exactly do you want to achieve? given that you want to store all elements in a vector, you only have access to `Element` later anyways

Comment: Typo - sure; just be aware that it still produced valid c++ and you would have returned an rvalue reference...

Comment: @fdan chaining: Circle{}.SetStrokeWidth(16).SetCircleCenter({0, 0}). SetStrokeWidth returns a reference to Element, so SetCircleCenter is unavailable.

Comment: @magom001 covariants won't make you happy in this case. this will only work as long as you know what type an element is (and please, do not upcast). the information is lost once you store the cirle as an element. if you go for CRTP you can't store the elements in homogeneous lists. I would drop the idea of chaining in base classes (if you need to access non-base functions)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to share implementations *and* preserve type information, the CRTP is what you need:

```
struct ElementBase { };

template <class Concrete>
struct Element : ElementBase {

    Concrete &setStrokeWidth(int width) {
        // Actual implementation...
        (void) width;

        return cthis();
    }

private:
    friend Concrete;
    Element() = default;

    Concrete &cthis() { return static_cast<Concrete &>(*this); }
    Concrete &cthis() const { return static_cast<Concrete const &>(*this); }
};

struct Circle : Element<Circle> {
    Circle &SetCircleCenter(int x, int y) {
        // Actual implementation...
        (void) x;
        (void) y;

        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    Circle c;
    c.setStrokeWidth(4).SetCircleCenter(0, 0);
}
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/54jBbBKQ5Ilbx7AK)

Comment: one little thing missing: how do I put objects of type Element into a vector<unique_ptr<Element>>?

Comment: found an answer: derived Element from a non template Base class. Make unique_ptr<Base>. Would you mind adding it to your solution, so that others would not have to read through the comments?

Comment: @magom001 certainly, but do note that, due to the issue described in lubgr's answer, you won't be able to call the functions dynamically from the base class. It can be circumvented, though, if you need that.

Comment: sure, in my particular case I only need to call a ToString method which I declare pure virtual in the Base class and override in subclasses. That's what chaining was intended for: you call Svg::Document::Add(Svg::Circle{}.SetCenter({0,0}).SetRadius(2)), the Add method does vector<Base>.emplace_back(make_unique<Circle>(circle))
When I need to generate an svg I just iterate over all the elements in vector and call ToString on each.

Answer (score 4):

With covariant return types, you can

```
class Element {
  public:
    // ...

    virtual Element& refToThis() { return *this; };
};
```

and in derived classes

```
class Derived : public Element {
  public:
    // ...

    Derived& refToThis() override { return *this; };
};
```

which lets you handle `Derived` instances as `Derived` instances when the static type is `Derived` (e.g. inside `Derived` itself). When tht static type is `Element`, the return type of `refToThis()` is, too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I still don't get it. The base method not just simple returns a ref. It does some logic etc. Does it mean that I have to reimplement the method for each derived class?

Comment: Yes, if you want the derived type to be available through `SomeDerivedClass::refToThis()`, then every subclass has to implement this member function.

Answer (score 1):

For comparison:

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

Derived d;
Base* p = &d; // points to a Base that in reality is a derived
Base& b =  d; // in this respect, references do not differ...

// and you can get the original type back:
auto dr = static_cast<Derived&>(b);  // if you know 100% for sure that b is a Derived
auto dp = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(p); // if p might point to another type; you get
                                     // a null pointer back, if it does
```

There is absolutely no difference with returning pointers or references to `this`/`*this`, so yes, you can safely do so.

Edit:

> `Circle().SetStrokeWidth(16).SetCircleCenter({0, 0})`. SetStrokeWidth returns a reference to Element, so SetCircleCenter is unavailable.

In this case, you are a bit in trouble, though. As [lubgr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9593596/lubgr) [denoted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56423349/1312382) already, you can solve the issue by overriding with co-variant return type – and yes, this would mean that you'd have to override each function separately. Alternatively, you can save all this hassle using [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template <typename T>
class SomeAppropriateName : public Element
{
public:
    T& setStrokeWidth(unsigned int width)
    {
        Element::setStrokeWidth(width);
        return static_cast<T&>(*this);
    }
};

class Circle : public SomeAppropriateName<Circle>
{
    // the overrides needed are inherited...
};
```

For this approach, original functions from `Element` class need to be *non*-virtual (thanks @[Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3233393/quentin) for the hint; actually an advantage as virtual function calls are more costly...); in the template, the argument (`T`, i. e. `Circle`) is not yet completely defined (with CRTP pattern) and the compiler wouldn't be able to check if the return type really is co-variant. So actually, we are just shadowing the base class' function.

This is still no disadvantage compared to overriding: The co-variant return type will only be available if the (virtual) function is called on the object directly anyway:

```
Circle c;
c.setStrokeWidth(7).setCenter();

Element& e = c;
e.setStrokeWidth(7).setCenter(); // fails with both variants, i.e. even if you
                                 // implement co-variant override
```

Comment: This, alas, does not work, since `Circle` (aka `T`) is not complete when `setStrokeWidth` is declared, and its inheritance graph is unknown. Thus the covariance of the return types cannot be verified and the code does not compile.

Comment: Still no dice (I stumbled into it while writing my answer...) -- even without an explicit `override` the signatures match so the check is performed. I think that's only solvable by using another name (or signature) for the function, *à la* NVI. Here's a [demo of the issue](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XJEiYrHTaoYXxMRR).

Comment: Edit: hold up, *your* code works on Clang as well. What did I do wrong...

Comment: Got it: your base class function is *not* `virtual`. I'm not crazy yet, yay!

Comment: Just add `virtual` to `Element::setStrokeWidth` in your demo and you'll see it :)