# How to implement method chaining with inheritance?

Tags: c++, crtp, method-chaining

My problem is that I can't chain methods from `Derived` class when I already used `Base` class methods. I tried to mix topmost answers from [Returning a reference to the derived class from a base class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56423269/returning-a-reference-to-the-derived-class-from-a-base-class-method) and [CRTP and multilevel inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174441/crtp-and-multilevel-inheritance), but the problem is one of them is always returning the same object, the other is returning `void`. I want `Base` class being able to be inherited by any other class.

[The naive solution to this problem is to make `a()` virtual and override it in class `Derived`. But what if `Base` is inherited by 100 other classes and have 100 other methods to override? This is not scaling good.]
[The other naive solution is to call methods from `Derived` class first, then from `Base`, but... just no]

So, is it possible to somehow compile the following snippet in native C++? (I am not interested in boost solutions). It would be ideal if `main()`'s code wouldn't change.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T = void>
class Base
{
public:
    T& a();
 };

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
public:
    Derived& b() {std::cout << "b\n"; return *this;}
};


int main()
{
    Base base;
    base
        .a()
    ;
    
    Derived derived;
    derived
        .a()
        .b()
    ;
    
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
T& Base<T>::a()
{
    std::cout << "a\n";
    if(std::is_same<T, void>::value)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    else
    {
        return static_cast<T&>(*this);
    }
}
```

If only i could write `template <typename T = Base> class Base { ...` :)

Comment: `typename T = void` would be problematic with `T&`...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the quesition is about but, is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/xKv43f) what you want?

Comment: Yes @TedLyngmo it is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I couldn't accept your solution from comments.

Comment: That's ok. I upvoted Jarod42's answer myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it is what you want, but with C++17 and `if constexpr`, you might do:

```
template <typename T = void>
class Base
{
public:
    auto& a()
    {
        std::cout << "a\n";
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, void>) {
            return *this;   
        } else {
            return static_cast<T&>(*this);
        }
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6f9e6ae8075e840)

Before, you might use specialization.

Comment: What do you mean by "Before, you might use specialization"?

Comment: Specialize the whole class: `template <typename T> class Base { T& a() { return static_cast<T&>(*this); }  }; template<> class Base<void> { Base& a() { return *this; } }` or specialize the method (return type should then be `std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, void>, Base, T>`)

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful.